# TYPO3: Form properties.fluidAdditionalAttributes.placeholder translation

Tags: forms, typo3, yaml, contact-form

I'm working on translating my Typo3 page.

Now I've come to my contact form which I want to translate. From the [Typo3 Documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/8.7/Concepts/FormConfigurationFormDefinition/Index.html) I've found that I need something like this:

```
contact.element.subject.properties.fluidAdditionalAttributes.placeholder
```

...as the translation ID inside my locallang.xlf file. I've linked my CustomFormSettings.yaml via TypoeScript, in there set the translation path to my extension and created a contact form.

I was actually able to translate the submit button for example and other buttons. But I can't get the placeholder inside my contact form to get translated, they all fallback to the value set in the contact form not the translation.

I'm guessing I'm handling the fluidAdditionalAttributes property wrong but I've tested lots of other combinations then the above.

What is the exact line I have to type inside my translation ID?

Here is my complete contact form:

```
renderingOptions:
  submitButtonLabel: Submit
identifier: contact
label: Contact
type: Form
prototypeName: frameform
finishers:
  -
    options:
      subject: 'Your message: {subject}'
      recipientAddress: mail@mail.com
      recipientName: 'Recipient Name'
      senderAddress: '{email}'
      senderName: '{name}'
      replyToAddress: ''
      carbonCopyAddress: ''
      blindCarbonCopyAddress: ''
      format: html
      attachUploads: true
      translation:
        language: ''
    identifier: EmailToReceiver
  -
    options:
      subject: 'We have received: {subject}'
      recipientAddress: '{email}'
      recipientName: '{name}'
      senderAddress: mail@mail.com
      senderName: 'Sender Name'
      replyToAddress: ''
      carbonCopyAddress: ''
      blindCarbonCopyAddress: ''
      format: html
      attachUploads: true
    identifier: EmailToSender
  -
    options:
      pageUid: '7'
      additionalParameters: ''
    identifier: Redirect
renderables:
  -
    renderingOptions:
      previousButtonLabel: 'Previous step'
      nextButtonLabel: 'Next step'
    identifier: mainPage
    type: Page
    renderables:
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        identifier: name
        label: Name
        type: Text
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            placeholder: Name
            required: required
        validators:
          -
            identifier: NotEmpty
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        identifier: subject
        label: Subject
        type: Text
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            placeholder: Subject
            required: required
        validators:
          -
            identifier: NotEmpty
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        identifier: email
        label: Email
        type: Text
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            placeholder: 'Email address'
            required: required
        validators:
          -
            identifier: NotEmpty
          -
            identifier: EmailAddress
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        identifier: message
        label: Message
        type: Textarea
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            placeholder: Message
            required: required
            minlength: '10'
            maxlength: '512'
        validators:
          -
            identifier: NotEmpty
          -
            options:
              minimum: '10'
              maximum: '512'
            identifier: StringLength
  -
    renderingOptions:
      previousButtonLabel: 'Previous step'
      nextButtonLabel: 'Next step'
    identifier: summarypage
    label: 'Summary page'
    type: SummaryPage
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override your placeholders in a locallang.xlf like this: `element.<field-identifier>.properties.placeholder`

**example:**

```
<trans-unit id="element.firstname.properties.placeholder">
    <source>Your first name</source>
    <target>Ihr Vorname</target>
</trans-unit>
```